# ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this weird behaviour of a page. The page loads, but after a second or two it turn blank.
In FireFox console, i get this error:
**ReferenceError: $ is not defined @https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js:4**.
In chrome I don't get any error, but the page still turns blank, and it happens only in this particular page.

The page uses jquery and jquery ui and I am trying to put some content in tabs.
The jquery script is included before any other javascript in the page.

The page is the following : http://www.upnext.eu/tv-schedule.html
Or you can view the source code here http://pastebin.com/R8f7xNHd.
The page is 100% HTML 5 valid and this happens only on this page.
Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gTOP.js` file that you're including is doing a `document.write`, which is overwriting your page. It's hard to tell without analyzing your code, but it appears that you're dynamically loading HTML which contains this script. If this script is doing a `document.write`, it is incompatible with dynamic loading. You may have to change your design to avoid doing this.

Your page has multiple JS errors as well, but that's not what's causing the page to blank out.

Comment: The gTOP.js is a script for web statistics site. In some way I am loading the html dynamically, but just by including a html file with php (require_once) and the tab containers are in that file. Can you tell me what tool did you use to view those js errors ?

Comment: I used IE 9's developer tools and did step debugging getting to the `document.write` line, which overwrote the page.

Comment: And it's not the `require_once` that's the issue; there's some JavaScript causing this script to get included. I suspect you have some widget that is doing the dynamic loading.